# How do I know if my WIndows 7 is genuine? If it isn't can I Still upgrde to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I want to upgrade my Windows 7 Ultimate to windows 10, but I don't know whether I am using genuine Windows or not.

I have a icon to upgrade my device to Windows 10.

Will the upgrade work if my Windows 7 is not genuine?

Comment: Look at the sticker on your Windows 7 device if it doesn't say Windows 7 Ultimate or you don't have the COA to Windows 7 Ultimate it's unlikely it's genuine otherwise you would know it was.  If you upgrade a pirated installation you end up with a pirated version of Windows 10 obviously

Comment: Unless you have a black screen with a tattoo in the corner saying 'this version of windows is not genuine' then it *thinks* it is, which is actually all that counts for the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a black desktop with a tattoo in the bottom right corner saying 'this version of windows is not genuine' then it *thinks* it is, which is actually all that counts for the upgrade.

Double-check by right clicking My Computer & get Properties. You should see a Genuine badge bottom right, & left of that 'windows is activated'.

Comment: That is not the case always, you can find so many softwares online to patch windows (which removes the **not genuine** text ).

Comment: hmm... not something I've seen [or tried] but it would seem like an odd way to go about things... the user would find out first time they checked for updates